# как сделать форму обратной связи на angular c валидацией и отправкой на почту?

Tags: angularjs

Например есть поля:

1. имя пользователя
2. e-mail
3. Сообщение

Нужно:

1. валидация на все поля;
2. кнопку отправить сделать таким образом чтобы избежать многократного нажатия

```
<form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal margin_auto form-wrap">
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="userFirstName" ng-model="firstName" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="[a-zA-Z]"
                   class="form-control"  placeholder="Имя" required >
            <div ng-messages="myForm.userFirstName.$error">
                <div class="errormesage" ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input name="userEmail" type="email" size="50" ng-model="email"
                   class="form-control required email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"
                   required>
            <div ng-messages="myForm.userEmail.$error">
                <div class="errormesage" ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
                <div class="errormesage" ng-message="email">Your email address is invalid</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <textarea type="text" name="userMessage" ng-model="message" class="form-control" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="500"
                      placeholder="Сообщение" rows="6"
                      required ></textarea>
            <div ng-messages="myForm.userMessage.$error" ng-if="myForm.userMessage.$dirty">
                <div class="errormesage" ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
                <div class="errormesage" ng-message="minlength">Message must be over 100 characters</div>
                <div class="errormesage" ng-message="maxlength">Message must not exceed 1000 characters</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary send-btn">Отправить</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Я хотел бы реализовать без использования php.

Comment: Angular на почту отправить не может, он может отправить на сервер данные, т.ч. должна быть серверная часть, которая эти данные примет и уже она - отправит на почту.

Comment: Это я понимаю, это мне и нужно

Comment: Может вы б тогда написали какой язык на сервере используется, показали бы код формы, и тогда можно было бы подумать, почему она у вас не работает… а если просто как сделать - так даже в доках к Angular есть пример с валидацией форм - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается, или вы хотите, чтобы кто-нибудь другой сделал вместо вас вашу работу?

Comment: @K.. ошибаетесь. В современных браузерах это уже возможно. http://emailjs.org/

Comment: Я не прошу сделать кого-то, я хочу что бы показали рабочий пример. Для кто не желает делится знаниями и опытом тех  я ни о чем не прошу, можете  ничего не отвечать

Comment: @Oceinic, покажите пример, так чтоб прям из любого браузера, а не *"In order to communicate over TCP the IMAP and SMTP components require apis that are currently only supported natively by Firefox OS."*

Comment: @radik_zu, вот вы пишите - *Я хотел бы реализовать без использования php*,  так а на чем тогда должна быть серверная часть?…

Comment: @K.. прочитайте предложение, следующее за тем, что Вы процитировали. В нем говорится, что в остальных браузерах это  работает после загрузки дополнительных скриптов (shims)

Comment: PHP не единственное решение.   На js!       К..

Comment: @radik_zu, да, PHP - не единственное, но мы ж не загадки отгадываем, так и написали бы на каком

Comment: @Oceinic, мы же тут об обычном браузере говорим, да? Если покажите пример - буду оч. благодарен.

Comment: @K.. , я невнимательно прочитал. Там говорится про FirefoxOS а не про FirefoxBrowser. Обновил свой ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> валидация на все поля

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

> кнопку отправить сделать таким образом чтобы избежать многократного нажатия

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807471/prevent-multiple-form-submissions-using-angular-js-disable-form-button

> email

Есть множество разнообразных способов решения этой проблемы. Традиционные - php, python, nodejs. Быстрые - облачные сервисы вроде https://sendgrid.com/ . У последнего есть неофициальные модули [для angular](https://github.com/ckelsey/ckc-angularjs-sendgrid)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю Вам воспользоваться несколькими способами.
1. Для валидации с помощью html можете использовать input[email] - но стоит обратить внимание на поддержку различных версий браузеров http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/type.

Также предлагаю воспользоваться регулярными выражениями и ng-pattern.
Документация тут https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input.

2. с помощью Angular заблокировать кнопку после нажатия используя директиву ng-disabled = "expression" на кнопке и поставив expression в true. Когда вы получите данные с сервера то снова можно ставить в false.

Отправка данных на сервер осуществляется с помощью $http. 
Так же можно использовать $resource, документацию можно прочитать на офф сайте.